# ODE computational ending issue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After turning $y'$ = $\frac{(4y-3x)}{(2x-y)}$ into a homogenous equation and applying partial fractions, I get (and I rechecked the calculation, I don't think there's an error) $\frac{1}{4} ln\vert v-1\vert - \frac{5}{4} ln \vert v+3\vert = ln\vert{x}\vert + C$ where $v$ = $\frac{y}{x}$ and $C$ is a constant of integration.

Question is: what do I do from here to finish solving the equation? The solution manual says I should be getting $\vert{y-x}\vert = C \vert{y+3x}\vert^{5}$. But I have no idea how it got that from what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from 
$$
\frac{1}{4} \ln\vert v-1\vert - \frac{5}{4} \ln \vert v+3\vert = \ln\vert{x}\vert + C
$$
Using properties of logarithm:
$$
\ln\vert v-1
\vert^\frac{1}{4}-\ln\vert v+3\vert^\frac{5}{4}=\ln\vert x\vert+\ln(C)\to\\
\ln\left(\frac{\vert v-1\vert^\frac{1}{4}}{\vert v+3\vert^\frac{5}{4}}\right)=\ln(C\vert x\vert)\to\\
\frac{\vert v-1\vert^\frac{1}{4}}{\vert v+3\vert^\frac{5}{4}}=C\vert x\vert
$$
Substitute $v=\frac{y}{x}$
$$
\frac{\vert \frac{y}{x}-1\vert^\frac{1}{4}}{\vert \frac{y}{x}+3\vert^\frac{5}{4}}=C\vert x\vert\to\frac{\vert \frac{y}{x}-1\vert}{\vert \frac{y}{x}+3\vert^5}=C^4\vert x\vert^4 \to \vert x\vert\left\vert \frac{y}{x}-1\right\vert=\left\vert \frac{y}{x}+3\right\vert^5C^4\vert x\vert^5\to\\
\vert y-x\vert=C^*\vert y+3x\vert^5
$$